# Como Trazer os 2 maiores valores de cada id diferente - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Montei uma planilha pra facilitar a compreensão da minha dúvida.

**Como selecionar apenas as 2 "duas" maiores mensalidades de casa sala?**

Só consegui trazer o maior valor de cada sala, queria trazer as 2 maiores mensalidades de cada sala. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

```
SELECT E.ID_SALA, 
       (SELECT MAX(E2.MENSALIDADE)
       FROM ESCOLA E2
       WHERE E2.ID_SALA  = E.ID_SALA)
       AS MAIOR_VALOR
FROM ESCOLA E
GROUP BY E.ID_SALA
ORDER BY E.ID_SALA;
```

Exemplo do banco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado da Query que estou tentando conseguir

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize a função `DENSE_RANK` para obter o resultado desejado:

```
SELECT x.id_sala,
       x.mensalidade
  FROM (SELECT *,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY e.id_sala ORDER BY e.mensalidade DESC) AS colocacao
          FROM escola e) x
  WHERE x.colocacao <= 2
  ORDER BY x.colocacao
```

No exemplo acima o `PARTITION BY` irá separar a numeração que retornará na coluna `colocacao` por `id_sala` com uma ordenação de `1 ~ N`. Logo após isso, filtre pelas colocações menores ou iguais a 2, obtendo assim os 2 maiores.

---

> [**DENSE_RANK**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm)
>
> `DENSE_RANK` computes the rank of a row in an ordered group of rows and returns the rank as a `NUMBER`.

Em tradução livre:

> `DENSE_RANK` calcula a classificação de uma linha em um grupo ordenado de linhas e retorna a classificação como `NUMBER`.

Comment: E quando há choque de `e.mensalidade`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado um `rank` diferente será dado pra cada um dos registros, mesmo os iguais